# how to convert html source with all formating into rtf string in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have creates a html page and want to convert into rtf string. But the all format not show in rtf string.  eg.  tag not showing in the rtf string.
Kindly help me.

```
 WebBrowser reportWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();

                reportWebBrowser.CreateControl();
                reportWebBrowser.DocumentText = _url;
                while (reportWebBrowser.DocumentText != _url)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                reportWebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
                Application.DoEvents();
                reportWebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
                Application.DoEvents();
                reportWebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
                Application.DoEvents();

                reportWebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);

                Application.DoEvents();
                RichTextBox reportRichTextBox = new RichTextBox();
                reportRichTextBox.Paste();
                String f = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
                reportRichTextBox.SaveFile(f);
                html=  System.IO.File.ReadAllText(f) ;
```

Comment: Are you trying to get raw text? Or you want to get the XML source?

Comment: Actully I want to rtf string like below given with all html format with text. eg. {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sb100\sa100\f0\fs24 lklllkjh\line erertrtr\line teter\line trtr\line\line rrt\line ert\line rrert\line erer\line\line sdfdfd\line werterter\par
\pard\f1\fs17\par
}

Comment: So you want to the json?

Comment: basically my recuriment is that i want to dispaly formated text into crystal report. There are three value in text interpretation one is none and second is  HTML and third is RTF. So I want to save my html editor formated text into rtf format using above given code. But the converted rtf some format missing.

Comment: kindly help me.